# How to avoid memory leaks in C GTK (using libxml)

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, libxml2

My code suffers huge memory leaks as Valgrind reveals. I'm reading xml files and I don't know the right way to copy the string values into my structure without having memory losses.

I've tried not to duplicate strings removing the `g_strdup` in the `on_button1_clicked` function, but in the case it's simply not working (no output).

C file:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <glib-object.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib/gprintf.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct {
    gchar *name;
    gint *age;
} item_struct;


typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *main_win;
    GtkWidget *button1;
    item_struct item[10];
    gint *item_index;
    gchar *local_path;
} app_widgets;


void on_button1_clicked (GtkButton *button, app_widgets *app_wid)
{
    g_printf("Button clicked !\n");

    int i;
    xmlDoc          *doc;
    xmlNodePtr      root, node, unode;
    gchar           *filename = g_strdup_printf("%s/test.xml",app_wid->local_path);

    doc = xmlReadFile((char*)filename, NULL, XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS);
    root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    if(root == NULL){
        g_printf("%s: Document is empty!\n",filename);
        return;
    }
    else {

        node = root->children; //item

        i=0;
        while(node != NULL) {

            unode = node->children;

            xmlChar *xml_name = xmlNodeGetContent(unode);
            app_wid->item[i].name = g_strdup((gchar*)xml_name);
            xmlFree(xml_name);

            unode = unode->next;

            xmlChar *xml_age = xmlNodeGetContent(unode);
            app_wid->item[i].age =  GINT_TO_POINTER((gint)g_ascii_strtoll(g_strdup((gchar*)xml_age),NULL,10));
            xmlFree(xml_age);

            i++;
            node = node->next;

        }
        app_wid->item_index = GINT_TO_POINTER((gint)i);

    }

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    xmlCleanupParser();
    g_free(filename);


    for(i=0;i<GPOINTER_TO_INT(app_wid->item_index);i++) {

         g_printf("%d name:%s age:%d\n",i,app_wid->item[i].name,GPOINTER_TO_INT(app_wid->item[i].age));

    }
}

void on_main_win_destroy(GtkWidget *object)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    app_widgets *widgets = g_slice_new(app_widgets);

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "test52.glade", NULL);

    widgets->main_win = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "main_win"));
    widgets->button1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button1"));

    widgets->local_path = g_strdup("/home/bobby/tmptest52");

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, widgets);
    gtk_widget_show(widgets->main_win);
    g_object_unref(builder);
    gtk_main();

    g_slice_free(app_widgets, widgets);
    return 0;
}
```

glade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="main_win">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_main_win_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkFixed" id="fixed1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Test</property>
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_button1_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">144</property>
            <property name="y">81</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

test.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
  <item>
    <name>Georges</name>
    <age>19</age>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Arthur</name>
    <age>53</age>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Louisa</name>
    <age>22</age>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Walter</name>
    <age>42</age>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Richard</name>
    <age>28</age>
  </item>
</document>
```

I was expecting removing the `g_strdup` would do, but even with the `(gchar*)` cast, the values are not passing.

Update - report from valgrind (there's 2 times the same error but I'm only copying one):

```
==5956== 645 bytes in 215 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6,472 of 6,728
==5956==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5956==    by 0x5A0B7B8: g_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2)
==5956==    by 0x5A2458E: g_strdup (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2)
==5956==    by 0x4010E4: on_button1_clicked (main.c:68)
==5956==    by 0x57791D3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.2)
==5956==    by 0x57939A5: g_signal_emit_valist (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.2)
==5956==    by 0x579408E: g_signal_emit (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.2)
==5956==    by 0x4F5A6AC: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==5956==    by 0x4F5A714: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==5956==    by 0x57791D3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.2)
==5956==    by 0x57939A5: g_signal_emit_valist (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.2)
==5956==    by 0x579408E: g_signal_emit (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.2)
```

Comment: Where does valgrind say the memory is being leaked? It'd probably be worth including that part of the report to your question

Comment: It is precisely on those two 'g_strdup' line in the button function. I'll add what valgrind reports.

Comment: [1] Why are you using `g_strdup((gchar*)xml_age)` instead of simply `(gchar*)xml_age`? This is exactly the place where you lose memory. One of the places, to be precise, but anyway. [2] `app_wid->item[i].name = g_strdup((gchar*)xml_name)` first needs you to free the previous `app_wid->item[i].name`, otherwise you are going to leak it.

Comment: I don't know why, but it's not working without the 'g_strdup'. Anyway, I ended up leaving it and, indeed, 'g_free(app_wid->item[i].name)' before. Valgrind still report the same leaks, but actually it's not leaking anymore. Thanks guys for your comments !

Comment: Note that you can answer your own questions. If your problem is solved, you could also consider to delete the question as it's unlikely to help people in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I'm answering my own question.

I was not aware that I had to beware using `g_strdup` and all GTK-Glib functions returning newly-allocated strings. I thought I could use them as much I wanted providing the returning string did go in a predefined `gchar*`, because I thought GTK would gracefully free itself the content of that variable. But that's not the case.

So, before using one of these function, we have to `g_free` them, unless we get memory leaks.

I guess this will help people not spending hours wondering what's happening (as I did). I'm not saying that this is not written anywhere, but that it's possible to tinker with GTK strings for hundreds of hours without knowing that.

I still don't know why the direct attribution `app_wid->item[i].name = (gchar*)xml_name` is not working. But that doesn't really matter as there's this other way to do it (`g_free` the value, then `g_strdup` it).